# Nativescript image area coordinates tap events like HTML Image Map

Tags: nativescript

For a vehicle inspection app, I need to display a flat vector image of a generic vehicle and allow the user to tap areas of that image to select that part of the vehicle and record any damage.

I have a hybrid app that implements this functionality using an HTML image map e.g.

```html
<img src="flat-vehicle-condition-vector.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="Front Nearside Wheel" title="Front Nearside Wheel" href="Front Nearside Wheel" coords="332,171,34" shape="circle">
    <area target="_self" alt="Bonnet" title="Bonnet" href="Bonnet" coords="230,290,231,378,362,398,359,262" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="Front Bumper" title="Front Bumper" href="Front Bumper" coords="88,225,52,441" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Is there a plugin or an approach to achieve this in NativeScript, please?